# Getting data from MySQL into Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, mysql

I am preparing a Word document with fields that will be populated from MySQL. As an example, I have the following sentence in my document:

The value of your portfolio is `$xxxx`.

`xxxx` is the result of the following query which I would like to send to MySQL:

```
SELECT sum(colA) WHERE colB='yourname' colC='equity'
```

So my questions are:

1. How to connect Word to MySQL?
2. How to send queries to MySQL to get results?
3. How to create and use merge fields to display those results dynamically in my document?

Some more info:

I am trying to create an automated dynamic report template in Word. I want to be able to copy over this template, change a few parameters and then refresh the connection to MySQL. The MySQL 'fields' (like `xxxx` above) in the template will be refreshed automatically. The copy of the Word document will then be converted to pdf and emailed to the audience.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Word should be able to use the standard MySQL ODBC driver - - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-wordexcel.html

Comment: Thanks. That answers part 1. But I need to understand how to use this connection as specified in parts 2 and 3.

Comment: It seems more likely that you'll want to get the data into Excel and merge it into Word from there... but you aren't telling us what you are *actually* trying to accomplish.  You're telling us how you are trying to accomplish it.  What is the purpose of the Word document?  Why is it a Word document, not something more portable like PDF or HTML?  Who will be reading it?  Why can they be trusted to access the data directly from the database?  These all probably have sensible, perhaps even obvious (to you) answers, but for now I can imagine no useful scenario for MySQL > Word.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have added some more info in the last para of my question for benefit of everyone. To your other questions - I am using Word because I don't know HTML and I guess non-coders will be more comfortable with Word. There are a lots of charts and tables which are easier for me to do in Word. Since only a read-only access is required and the Word doc itself is never exposed to anyone, I don't think there are too many security issues. I could be wrong about this though.

Comment: @KMLN Added 2 more options.  They are very similiar, but in one I pre-created the DSN before launching MS Word.  The second I had issues where it would save it, but that could just be a quirk of the VM I was testing in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **HAVE** to have the **MariaDB ODBC connector**

[Here is the connector 32 bit](https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/odbc/connector-odbc-3.0.2/mariadb-connector-odbc-3.0.2-win32.msi)
[Here is the connector 64 bit](https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/odbc/connector-odbc-3.0.2/mariadb-connector-odbc-3.0.2-win64.msi)

The MariaDB is a fork of the mysql project so this connector should work just fine for mysql.

Had a bizarre error where it wouldn't save the dsn connection
setting up from control panel before going into MS word

ODBC tools
[image: ODBC tools]

Pre-existing connection(s) shown here
[image: Pre-existing connection(s) shown here]

MariaDB connection
[image: MariaDB connection]

Name and description
[image: Name and description]

Database login details
[image: Database login details]

SQL NOW
[image: SQL NOW]

Options
[image: Options]

Optional encryption
[image: Optional encryption]

More options
[image: More options]

DSN setup
[image: DSN setup]

Launch word

New Source
[image: New Source]

Advanced
[image: Advanced]

specify DSN from before
[image: specify DSN from before]

Select table(s)
[image: Select table(s)]

Final DONE!!! :)
[image: DONE!]

Here are all the columns in my table
[image: Here are all the columns in my table]

Comment: This step-by-step answer is painless. I followed it without a flaw.

Comment: @Kar.ma  I am glad you liked it, it took a while to verify and test each step.

Answer (score 0):

The Mysql or mariadb ODBC connector must be downloaded and installed.  You must match the 32/64 to your version of MS Office.

Go into the control panel
Then All Control Panel Items
Finally Administrative Tools

Open **ODBC Data Sources (32-bit)** and/or **ODBC Data Sources (64-bit)**

Setup the detail here, and then you can just pick it off the list later.

[image: Step 1]

[image: select New source]

[image: This is where you setup the connection]
Option #2 only allow Excel or Access files.

[image: Start setting up the connection]
[image: mariadb connection]
[image: Build the DSN]
Click New
[image: Click new]
Select the Mysql ODBC driver
[image: Mysql ODBC]
Name the DSN
[image: Name it]
Click Finish
[image: Finish process]
[image: Database login details and database]
Finish this part up
[image: Done]
In the picture below I added username,password, and save password these fields will be blank when the dialog first re-appears.
[image: This is how it should look]
Select a table(s) from your database
[image: Select a table]
You might have to save your password here.
[image: Final screen]

---

[image: Once connected you get this]

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. However, by following the steps, I can only establish a connection to MySQL and if I go further, I can get a list of records as a table in Word. However, I am looking for more granular results, not tables and ideally define some fields (quick parts) to contain those results. Please look at my question - parts 2 and 3.

Comment: @KMLN finished the instructions.

Comment: @KMLN If you get stuck let me know which step.

Comment: Great, thanks @cybernard .. this is extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

**You will have to use the Maria DB ODBC connector to get an actual SQL query option**

I got stuck in a circular loop where it wouldn't save the DSN connection as a file.  It could be just a quirk on my VM, it may work for you.

It should be compatible with mysql.

[image: Step 1]

[image: New Source]

[image: Other Advanced]

[image: Select connection]

Use connection string and click build
[image: Use & build]
We need a **new** data source.
[image: New datasource]

Select MariaDB ODBC
[image: Select MariaDB ODBC]
[image: Name it]
Click Finish
[image: Review and finish]
[image: Next section description]
Test button populates drop down
[image: Test button populates drop down]

Here it is the moment you have been waiting for to enter your own SQL Statement.
[image: SQL Statement]

If you want to change these you can:
[image: Next]
Setup encryption  **OPTIONAL**
[image: Encryption]

Even more options
[image: Even more options]

Return screen looks like this
[image: Return screen looks like this]

Add and save the values
[image: Add and save the values]